# setting random value for cookies but cookie value is different than that which was supposed to be saved

Tags: php, cookies

COOKIES not being saved correctly. Random numbers change when its saved in cookies.
`$rand1 + $rand2` is different than that of what is saved in $_COOKIE['match'].

```
$rand1=rand(10,20);
$rand2=rand(10,20);
$SUMCAP = $rand1 + $rand2;
setcookie('match', $SUMCAP, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
```

expected result is `$_POST['addition_of_random_numbers_sent_through_post'] == $_COOKIE['match'];`

need to match cookie value to the value posted.
but cookie value must change on each page load.